# How does AUTOMOC adds files to mocs_compilation.cpp?

Tags: qt, cmake, moc

I'm porting a Qt project to CMake and after adding `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` I've started experiencing a bunch of compilation problems, which are triggered when trying to compile `mocs_compilation.cpp`, such as `error C2504: 'Lucene::Reader': base class undefined`.

After looking into `mocs_compilation.cpp`, I've found that the file is nothing more than a long list of `#include` statements bundling source files into a huge translation unit.

[CMake's documention](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#automoc) mentions the following about `mocs_compilation.cpp`;

> (...)
>
> Not included moc_.cpp files will be generated in custom folders to avoid name collisions and included in a separate <AUTOGEN_BUILD_DIR>/mocs_compilation.cpp file which is compiled into the target.
>
> (...)

With this in mind, how does AUTOMOC determine which files go into `mocs_compilation.cpp`?  And is there any way to keep source files out of `mocs_compilation.cpp` and build them separately?

Comment: The documentation clearly states how to skip files: "Source C++ files can be excluded from AUTOMOC processing by enabling SKIP_AUTOMOC or the broader SKIP_AUTOGEN."

Comment: @chehrlic I'm not sure you got my question right,but my question was on how to exclude the output from `mocs_compilation.cpp`, not from being moc-ed altogether. Bundling moc-ed files into a huge translation unit is a well known source of build problems, and not including some moc-ed files in `mocs_compilation.cpp` and instead handle them separately should be enough to avoid problems.

Comment: I never heard of any problems when the moc files were built in one single file. If you find one please provide a bug report to Qt or CMake. If you don't like automoc or qt_wrap_cpp() you can write your own functions and use them.

Comment: @chehrlicif you're curious you can run a couple of queries in stackoverflow to stumble upon questions regarding problems caused by AUTOMOC, including a rather notorious problem involving a problem introduced by cmake 3.9.  Nevertheless, I've circumvented my problem by using `qt5_wrap_cpp()` but it would be interesting to know how AUTOMOC generates `mocs_compilation.cpp` to be able to troubleshoot and avoid the problems it creates.

Comment: Please show the cmake or qt bug report so we can see what the actual problem is.

Comment: @chehrlic I'm sorry, how does that help clarify how automoc determines which files are included in mocs_compilation.cpp ? regarding problems related to how automoc generates code, if you're curious again you are free to search through stackoverflow for questions regarding them.

Comment: One solution I forgot is to add `#include "moc_foo.cpp"` as last line your your `foo.cpp`. This also allows some compilers to give additional warnings e.g. about unused members since it then sees the whole class in one compilation unit.